# Django: Store a CSS class in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, django-database

So I made an HTML button and on clicking to it, a CSS class is added to it using some Jquery/javascript logic. Is there any way I can store this animation on my database so that on page refresh the class should still stay. Or if I can do that with Javascript. A little guidance would be appreciated.

Regards
Fanceh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to achieve what you want. I would recommend using `localStorage` of user browser ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) to save that class:

```
localStorage.setItem('buttonClass', 'some-class');
```

And then later when you refresh the page just check that if `localStorage` has `buttonClass` key set.

```
const savedClass = localStorage.getItem('buttonClass');
if (savedClass) {
  // automatically add to your button
} else {
  // behave as usual
}
```

If you think that it is not permanent enough you can use Django session to store that value. This is better than storing it on some other table but much worse than using JavaScript along with local storage:

```
def your_view(request):
    button_class = request.session.get('saved_button_class')
    context = {
        'saved_button_class': button_class
    }
    render(request, 'templates/index.html', context=context)
```

In your template check for `saved_button_class` variable.

And you must implement new view that will accept AJAX request, telling that user have clicked that button.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def ajax_view(request):
    request.session['saved_button_class'] = 'button_class'
    return JsonResponse({'saved': True})
```

Then on page refresh, you will have `saved_button_class` on user's session already

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! Thanks alot sir :)